# Laravel string localization and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, localization, laravel-4

So recently i started to convert my jQuery stuff to AngularJS, but there was a solution what i did not think about.

Not all my pages will use Angular, and i am using Laravel's built in localization.

So the views used by Angular are just plain html, no php or blade included.

So i do not really want to mix the 2 in a view.

Where i use blade i use the built in function example: `{{ trans('user.first_name') }}`

But since i don't want to mix, and my AngularJS views are pure html, i do not want to use it this way `<?php echo trans('user.first_name') ?>` in my Angular view.

So i was thinking to include Angular localization for AngularJS, but maintaining 2 different localization structure will be a pain and building a good logic for it is another pain.

So anybody with a solution? currently i am clueless. Because for example with jQuery i did not had to worry about this, because it was just dom manipulation, but now its is more complex

Answer (score 3):

I have developed a package that create a JavaScript file from all Laravel's messages. I think you could use it to have access directly in Laravel.

Basically, after installing the package and running the bundled command you will have a global object: `windows.Lang`. From there you can do different basic operations such as:

**Get a localized message**

```
var message = Lang.get('messages.first_name');
```

**Get a localized message with replacements**

```
var message = Lang.get('messages.welcome', { name: 'Joe' });
```

**Change the current locale** (applies to JavaScript)

```
Lang.setLocale('es');
```

You can find more information: https://github.com/rmariuzzo/laravel-js-localization

Comment: will definitely take a look at it

Comment: Hi, i Tried to install your package using composer but it failed, using laravel 4.2 can you help me out? thx

Comment: Of course @DanielKatzan, create an issue at: https://github.com/rmariuzzo/Laravel-JS-Localization/issues/new let's see how can I help you ;)

Comment: https://github.com/rmariuzzo/laravel-js-localization - it support laravel 5.6 version ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with a ViewComposer:

> app/Http/ViewComposers/TranslateComposer.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class TranslateComposer
{
    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('jstrans', json_encode(trans('my_locale_resource')));
    }
}
```

> app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer(
        '*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\TranslateComposer'
    );
}
```

> resources/views/index.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var trans = JSON.parse('{!! $jstrans !!}');
</script>
```